# LD_PRELOAD causing Segmentation fault for linux commands

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a .so file which is used for finding memory leaks. I set the LD_PRELOAD env variable in the session in which I want to execute my target binary.
`export LD_PRELOAD=./memleakfinder.so` 
But once this environment variable is set, even a simple linux command like `ls` or `ps` is causing a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Why is that happening?I've overloaded versions of `malloc()`,`calloc()`,`realloc()`,`free()`,`new`,`new[]` etc. in that .so file.
The automatic bug reporting tool of CentOS6 is saying:
`source:coreutils  Problem:process /bin/ls was killed by signal 11(SIGSEGV)`. Clearly the library injection is causing the problem here. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure you **correctly** implemented those functions?

Comment: Use gdb to inspect the core dumps and see the stack trace at the point of crash

Comment: Before running it on the whole system, make test program which calls your functions and tests them.

Comment: Also remember that the `new` and `delete` functionality of C++ will most likely call `malloc` and `free` for the actual allocation/deallocation. So having those functions in the preloaded library may not work as you expect them too.

Comment: if you want to detect memory leaks, use valgrind! (of course, you might have other reasons for writing your own memory leak tool like entertainment or education)

Comment: And, why are you writing your own leak-detector? Why not use e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which can find other memory issues as well?

Comment: Valgrind is not suitable for the architecture. Though I've mentioned x86/CentOS here, my ultimate goal is to make it work on a Renesas SuperH RISC/Embedded Linux

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem when trying to override the malloc function.

For me, I was using `printf()` in my function declaration of `malloc()` (to see if it was working).

When I switched to `write()` instead or `printf()`, it worked. This is because some library functions, such as printf, may allocate memory for their operation. Consequently, if you use any of those functions in your library you risk getting into an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting an environmental variable, prepend the variable to the command you want to run/debug.

For example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./memleakfinder.so a.out
```

And the library will only be loaded for this one invocation of a.out instead of all commands in the current shell.

We cannot help you determine the cause of the segmentation fault without seeing some code.